# Intersection of infinitely many closed nested sets in a complete space

Tags: general-topology

$(X,d)$ is a complete metric space. It needs to be proved, that if $A_1\supset A_2\supset ...$ are non-empty closed sets and $A_n$ is a finite sum of closed sets with diameter $\leq 1/n$ then $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n$ is nonempty and compact.

The problem is I don't know how to start and I'm not quite sure how should I try to obtain the compactness of this intersection. As the closed sets are mentioned, I think it may have to do with Baire's category theorem, but I don't see nowhere dense sets here. Then again, it'd be easier if $diam\ A_n \longrightarrow 0$, but that doesn't necessarily have to be the case.

Comment: Does the term "total boundedness" ring a bell?

Comment: Partially. I suppose $A_n$ are totally bounded from the assumptions and complete as closed subsets of a complete space. Which makes them compact. So the intersection is definitely closed and bounded, because $A_1$ is bouned. Does that aslo prove it's nonempty?

Comment: No, none of the $A_n$ needs to be totally bounded. If any were, we could ignore all larger $A_m$ - i.e. those with smaller indices - and have a nested intersection of compact sets, where everything is rather immediate from the definitions. There is some more to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n = A$.
For each n let $\mathscr C_n$ be a finite set of closed, non-empty sets with diameter $< 1/n$ and $\cup \mathscr C_n = A_n$. Consider finite sequences of the form $<C_1, ...,C_n>$ with each $C_n \in \mathscr C_n$ and $C_1 \cap ... \cap C_n$ non-empty. Every member of every $\mathscr C_n$ is in at least one such sequence so there are infinitely many of them. But there are only finitely many possibilities for the first member so there is a $B_1 \in \mathscr C_1$ which is in infinitely many sequences. Similarly there is $B_2 \in \mathscr C_2$ which is second in infinitely many sequences starting with $B_1$. Inductively we get an infinite sequence $<B_n>$, every initial sequence of which is of the specified form. Any sequence $<x_n>$ with each $x_n \in B_n$ must be Cauchy and so has a limit, which will be a point in A.

Now, suppose $<F_n>$ is any sequence of closed subsets of A with the finite intersection property. Replace $A_n$ by $F_1\cap...\cap F_n$. This is still a union of finitely many closed sets of diameter less than $1/n$ so the same argument shows that $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} F_n$ is non-empty. Thus A is countably compact.

Let $\mathscr S = \{A \setminus C \mid C \in \mathscr C_n, n \in \Bbb N \}$. This is a sub-basis for the topology on A, showing it is second countable. Together with countably compact that implies it is compact.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $A_1 = \cup_{k=1}^{N} F_k^1$ is a disjoint union of closed sets. Then $A_n = \cup_{k=1}^{N} F_k^n$ where $F_k^n \subseteq F_k^1$. For simplicity we replace $F_k^n$ by $A_n$. Now we would like to show $\cap_n A_n$ is a singleton.

If $(A_n)$ is nonempty, pick $x_n \in A_n$.

For $n \geq m$, $x_n \in A_n \subseteq A_m$ and $x_m \in A_m$ implies $d(x_n, x_m) \leq diam(A_m) \leq \frac{1}{m}$.

Hence $(x_n)$ is Cauchy and convergent by completeness. Let $x = \lim_{n} x_n$.

We then see $x \in \cap_n A_n$. For $n \geq 1$, for $m \geq n$, $x_m \in A_n$ and therefore $x = \lim_m x_m \in A_n$ by the fact that $A_n$ is closed.

Finally, we see that $\cap_n A_n = \{x\}$ is a singleton. Assume $y \in \cap_n A_n \setminus \{x\}$. Then $d(y, x) > 0$.

Pick $m$ such that $diam(A_m) \leq \frac{1}{m} \leq \frac{d(y, x)}{2}$. Then $x, y \in A_m \subseteq \cap_n A_n$ and $d(y, x) > diam(A_m)$. Contradiction.

This shows that, in the original setting, $\cap_n A_n$ is a finite set since each $F_k^n$ is either empty or a singleton.

Comment: This theorem is due to Cantor. In fact, some texts use this theorem as a lemma of Baire's Theorem.

Comment: Oook, that's good to know, thank you :)

Comment: No, $A_n$ is a union (I interpret the word "sum" from the question as "union") of finitely many sets of diameter $\leqslant \frac{1}{n}$, but that does not imply that $\operatorname{diam}(A_n) \to 0$. As a simple counterexample, let $A_n = \{0,1\}$ for all $n$.

Comment: I am sorry I overlooked the word sum. So this is not exactly the Cantor theorem and the proof is not sufficient for the problem. @Jules: Could you please clarify what sense the sum is?

Comment: Well, I meant a union. That's also how I understand this question, it one of the exercises in my topology book.

Comment: I am sorry I am busy now. I would come back to this question once I finish up my things, if this is not yet solved. I feel like this edited version is very close to a sound proof, but whether the condition of the assumption of the disjoint union can be dropped is still questionable.